# mongodb atlas error! { "error": { "ok": 0, "code": 8000, "codeName": "AtlasError" }, "success": false }

Tags: mongodb-atlas

the error I want to connect with MongoDB atlas DB but there is an error!
{
"error": {
"ok": 0,
"code": 8000,
"codeName": "AtlasError"
},
"success": false
}

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your Mongodbatlas dashboard on left side click database access then select user which user you are using.
2. Then select the edit option.
   [image: Database Access and Edit]
3. scroll down and Expand the (specific privilege) option then click on add specific privilege.
   [image: Add specific privileges]
4. Select Role for your user but I want to suggest you (dbAdminAnyDatabase) will be full access to any database for your selected user.
   Then click update

[image: dbAdminAnyDatabase and update]